# Как посчитать точное время выполнения метода?

Tags: java, android

Вот у меня есть такой метод

```
@Override public double calculateMiddleVarOfAxisZ(double axisZ) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    countAxisZTimes++;
    countAxisZSum += axisZ;

    mapAxisZ.put(current, axisZ);

    if (mapAxisZ.size() == 1) {
        return axisZ;
    }

    Iterator iterator = mapAxisZ.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Long, Double> point = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        long pointTime = point.getKey();
        long difference = current - pointTime;

        if (difference > getTime(mapAxisZ)) {
            double val = point.getValue();
            countAxisZTimes--;
            countAxisZSum -= val;
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    double result = countAxisZSum / countAxisZTimes;
    Logger.logGeneral(String.valueOf(result) + " size : " + mapAxisZ.size());

    long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Logger.logGeneral("Start : " + startTime + " finish : " + finishTime + " Time diff Z: " + (
            finishTime
                    - startTime));
    return result;
}
```

Мне нужно посчитать точное время выполнения. В моем примере я снимаю время когда метод начал выполнение и когда заканчивает и считаю разницу

В последней строке вывожу лог вот что получается

```
Start : 1481102600075 finish : 1481102600075 Time diff Z: 0
```

Насколько я понимаю минимальная единица времени доступная из этого числа `1481102600075` это тысячная секунды(миллисекунда) 10 в 3 степени. Так как 1000 это секунда.

Так вот как в моем случае можно посчитать более точно? Может микросекунды или нано...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно получить текущее время в наносекундах: `System.nanoTime()`
Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--

Answer (score 2):

Не советую использовать `System.nanoTime()`, в своих измерениях. В документации этого метода написано :

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of currentTimeMillis().

Т.е. значения могут быть совсем не точные.

В измерении производительности слишком много нюансов, и с текущим подходом ваши значения не будут точны. Рекомендую, для подобных целей, использовать фреймворк [`jmh`](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

В крайнем случае, можете вызвать метод `N` раз, и затем суммарное время выполнения поделить на это `N` + не стоит забывать о разогревочных итерациях.

Comment: хмм... интересно. Но с фреймворком нужно разбираться, но вот попробую сейчас посчитать кол-во итераций и время

Comment: Зачем нужны разогревочные итерации? И как их лучше реализовать? И что это такое конкретно?

Comment: Разогревочные итерации - это простое выполнение кода время выполнение которого вы хотите замереть. Нужны они для того чтобы jit компилятор смог собрать достаточно информации о коде и приминить оптимизации. Те. у вас есть метод `method` вы его запускаете 10 раз без замеров а последующие разы уже замеряете время.

Answer (score 1):

Может подойти библиотека [Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo). Как указано в описании её репозитория, это средство логирования вызова аннотированных функций.

Comment: Вы пробовали  добавить эту библиотеку в свой проект? У меня не получается. Все сделал как написано по вашей ссылке, но все равно в лог ничего не выводит...

Comment: да, я использовал эту библиотеку, а логи искал вот по этим символам - "⇢ " и  "⇠ "